# Given a Hardy Field is it always possible to find a smooth representative of each germ?

Tags: real-analysis, model-theory

In this case I refer to a Hardy Field (of germs at infinity) $\mathcal{H}$ a a field of germs of real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that is closed under differentiation.

That is, if $\operatorname{germ}(f)$ is in $\mathcal{H}$ then there is a function $g$ such that $\operatorname{germ}(g) = \operatorname{germ}(f)$, $g$ is differentiable and $g'$, the derivative of germ is such that $\operatorname{germ}(g')$ is in $\mathcal{H}$.

I believe it is NOT always possible to find a smooth ($\mathcal{C}^\infty$) representative of every germ in $\mathcal{H}$. 
If such is the case, could you provide an example? If not, a reason (proof).

Comment: I seem to recall having a similar question some years back, about definable functions in an o-minimal expansion of the real numbers. It seems that in *all known* o-minimal structures (containing at least the field operations on $\mathbb{R}$), for each definable function $f$ there is a $C^\infty$ definable function $g$ which agrees with $f$ except at finitely many points. And yet, there is no known proof that this is the case in all o-minimal structures (or at least that was the case when I put the question to an expert). It's a perplexing situation.

Comment: @user43208 , see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121010/is-there-any-o-minimal-expansion-of-the-real-field-with-functions-of-growth-high

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks; I seem to remember that MO question and found it interesting. But you're not suggesting there's a connection with the question in my comment (aside from mention of o-minimality), are you? Is this a topic that interests you as well? Nice to see Santiago has similar concerns.

Comment: @user43208, no, you remembered something, and i found the question by the same guy. I do not know what the words mean except for Hardy field; my friend did his dissertation on those, under Rosenlicht.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hardy fields are the classes of germs that are closed under differentiation. This means, all the elements in a Hardy field are eventually differentiable.
This means, all germs and all their derivatives are differentiable as well, all elements of Hardy fields are eventually infinitely differentiable.

This excludes periodic functions and functions that have infinitely many arbitrarily large zeros as well (because their multiplicative inverses should be continuous and differentiable as well).